# A long table in the landscape page

Tags: tables

Please, I need your help to make a long table in one landscape page. I've tried to do that but I could not because of (1) table borders outside the page (please, see the pic), (2) the page header is still in the upper of page but in the vertical direction (please, see the pic), (3) the number of the page is also not in the correct position which should be in the bottom of the page.

Please, could you help me to make it within one landscape page borders. I will highly appreciate any help that I may get.

[image]
[image]

```
    %% ----------------------------------------------------------------
    %% Thesis.tex -- MAIN FILE (the one that you compile with LaTeX)
    %% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

    % Set up the document

    \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, arial, oneside]{Thesis}   % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn

    \usepackage{charter}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
    %\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
    %\renewcommand\familydefault{phv}



    %\graphicspath{{figs/}}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics to be in PDF format)

    % Include any extra LaTeX packages required
    \usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
    \usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
    \usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
    %\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  % Colours hyperlinks in blue, but this can be distracting if there are many links.

    \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}


    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{romannum}
    \usepackage{enumerate}


    %\usepackage{booktabs}
    %\usepackage[hmargin={30mm,25mm},vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
    %\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
    %\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}

    %\usepackage{enumitem}
    %\usepackage{etoolbox}
    %\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    %   \setlist[itemize]{  nosep,     % <-- new list setup
    %       leftmargin = *,
    %       before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
    %       after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    %   }
    %}
    %\usepackage{showframe}
    %\usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{ragged2e, tabularx}
    \usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
    \usepackage[skip=1ex,labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}

    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{%
        \small                              % for better fit text into cells
        \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth} % that caption width is equal table width
        \setlist[itemize]{  nosep,          % <-- new list setup
            leftmargin = *,
            before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
            after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
        }
    }% end of AtBeginEnvironment

    \AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
        \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
            wide,%leftmargin = *,
            before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
            after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
        }
    }% end of AtBeginEnvironment

    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\setlength\parskip{0.2\baselineskip}\arraybackslash}X}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}

    \usepackage[space]{grffile}
    \usepackage{latexsym}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
    \usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=red}
    % You can conditionalize code for latexml or normal latex using this.
    \newif\iflatexml\latexmlfalse
    \providecommand{\tightlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}%

    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.PDF,.png,.PNG,.jpg,.JPG,.jpeg,.JPEG}

    %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[british]{babel}


    % correct bad hyphenation here
    \hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
    \usepackage{siunitx} % For units
    \newcommand\mmfeed[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf,small},textfont={small}}
    \captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont={bf,small}, textfont={small}, subrefformat=parens} %<-----designing subcaption
    \newcommand{\myfigref}[2]{~\ref{#1}.\subref{#2}}% <---- a new macro for referring to a subfigure
    %    

    %\newpage
    %\bibliographystyle{plain}
    %\bibliography{bibliografia}

    % Change the text font
    \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
    \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
    %



    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{cleveref}


    % I added many usepackages
    %% ----------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{document}

        \begin{landscape}
    \vspace{-10pt} % I've tried to shift the table a little bit to the top but this command does not work here!
\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Characteristics of low and medium spatial resolution remote sensing systems and their applications}
    %{\small %
    \label{T2.1}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | p{6cm} |}
            \hline
            \textbf{Launch year} & \textbf{Satellite} & \textbf{Sensor} & \textbf{Spectral range\textsuperscript{a} (nm)} & \textbf{Bands\textsuperscript{b}} & \textbf{Pixel size\textsuperscript{c} (m)} & \textbf{Coverage\textsuperscript{d} (km)} & \textbf{Revisit time\textsuperscript{e} (days)} & \textbf{Dynamic range\textsuperscript{f} (bit)} & \textbf{Mapping scale} & \textbf{Applications} \\ 
            \hline
            1972  & Landsat-1, 2, 3  & MSS  & 500 - 1100 &  \vtop{\hbox{\strut 4 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 5 (Landsat-3 only)}} & 80 & 185 & 18 & 6 & 1:2500 - 1:100,000 & Land-use planning; vegetation inventories; crop growth and health assessments; discriminating different types and amounts of vegetation; and cartography \\ \hline
            1984 & Landsat-5 & TM & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 450 - 2,350}\hbox{\strut 10,400 - 12,350}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 6 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 1(T)}} & 30 & 185 & 16 & 8 & 1:2500 - 1:100,000 & Surface temperature; discriminating vegetation type; water penetration; plant and soil moisture measurements; and identification of hydrothermal alteration in certain rock types \\ \hline
            1997 & SeaStar & SeaWiFS & 402 - 885 & 8 (MS) & 1,100 & 2,800 & Daily & 10 & 1:100,000 - 1:500,000 & The concentration of microscopic marine plants; phytoplankton based on the colour of the ocean \\ \hline
            1998 & NOAA-15 & AVHRR/3 & 580 - 12,500 & 6 (MS) & 1,090 & 2,940 & Daily & 10 & 1:100,000 - 1:500,000 & Surface mapping (daytime); land–water boundaries; snow and ice detection; cloud mapping (daytime and night); sea surface temperature \\ \hline
            1999 & Terra \& Aqua & MODIS & 620 - 14,3385 & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 2 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 5 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 29 (MS \&T)}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 250}\hbox{\strut 500}\hbox{\strut 1000}} & 2,330 & Daily & 12 & 1:100,000 - 1:500,000 & Land, cloud, aerosols boundaries and properties; ocean colour, phytoplankton, biogeochemistry; atmospheric temperature; cirrus clouds and water vapour; ozone; surface and cloud temperature; cloud top altitude \\ \hline
            1999 & Terra & MISR & 425 - 886 & 4 (MS) & 275 & 360 & 9 & 14 & 1:100,000 - 1:500,000 & Land use; ocean colour; air pollution; volcanic eruptions; desertification; deforestation; and soil erosion \\ \hline
            1999 & Landsat7 & ETM+ & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 450 - 2,350}\hbox{\strut 10,400 - 12,500}\hbox{\strut 500 - 900}}  & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 6 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 1 (T)}\hbox{\strut 1 (PAN)}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 30}\hbox{\strut 60}\hbox{\strut 15}} & 185 & 16 & 8 & 1:2,500 - 1:100,000 & LAgriculture; forestry; land use; water resources and natural resource exploration; human population census and monitoring the growth of global urbanisation; deletion of coastal wetlands; and generating DEM \\ \hline
            1999 & Terra & ASTER & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 520 - 860}\hbox{\strut 1,600 - 2,430}\hbox{\strut 8,125 - 11,650}}  & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 3 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 6 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 5 (T)}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 15}\hbox{\strut 30}\hbox{\strut 90}} & 60 & 16 & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 8}\hbox{\strut 8}\hbox{\strut 12}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 1:2,500 - 1:40,000}\hbox{\strut 1:40,000 - 1:100,000}\hbox{\strut 1:100,000 - 1:500,000}} & Land surface climatology; vegetation and ecosystem dynamics; volcano monitoring; hydrology; geology and soils; land surface and land cover change \\ \hline
            2002 & SPOT5 & 2 HRGs & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 500 - 890}\hbox{\strut 1,580 - 1,750}\hbox{\strut 480 - 710}}  & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 3 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 1 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 1 (PAN)}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 10}\hbox{\strut 20}\hbox{\strut 5}} & 60 & 26 & 8 & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 1:10,000 - 1:25,000}\hbox{\strut 1:10,000 - 1:25,000}\hbox{\strut 1:7,500 - 1:25,000}} & Urban and rural planning; land use and Infrastructure planning; telecommunications; oil and gas exploration and mining; environmental assessment, natural disaster management; marine studies; agriculture; and 3D terrain modelling \\ \hline
            2013 & Landsat8 & OLI \& TIRS & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 435 - 1,551}\hbox{\strut 10,600 - 12,510}\hbox{\strut 503 - 676}}  & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 8 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 2 (T)}\hbox{\strut 1 (PAN)}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 30}\hbox{\strut 100}\hbox{\strut 15}} & 185 & 16 & 12 & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 1:80,000 - 1:100,000}\hbox{\strut 1:80,000 - 1:100,000}\hbox{\strut 1:2,500 - 1:40,000}} & Mineral exploration; vegetation analysis; large regional coverage; extensive archive for change detection; availability of imagery over cloud affected areas (detecting cirrus clouds); and coastal zone \\  \hline

            \multicolumn{11}{|l|}{\textsuperscript{a}Spectral resolution, \textsuperscript{b}MS multi-spectral bands, \textsuperscript{c}Spatial resolution, \textsuperscript{d}Swath-width, \textsuperscript{e}Temporal resolution, \textsuperscript{f}Radiometric resolution} \\

            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }

\end{table}

\end{landscape}
\clearpage

    \end{document}  % The End
    %% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @ Zarko - Please, help!

Comment: hi @Iris! how many rows has your table?

Comment: @Zarko-Thank you for your reply. It has 11 rows.

Comment: @Iris, thank you for info. than table in your *mwe* is complete. late evening i will look what i can do.

Comment: @Zarko-Thanks a lot. However, the solution that I've got takes many pages. It is possible to make the whole table in one landscape page, please?

Comment: @Zarko-I have edited my post. I have tried to put it in one landscape page. It looks good but the test is very small. The table is also close to the bottom of the page. I could not fix these issues. Please, see the code and the photo/pic.

Comment: @Iris, as you see n my answer below, it is not possible to fit your table in one page (assuming that you like to have readable table). firs i look if can do this with interchanges rows and columns, but result was worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that i'm to late with my answer :-), but anyway it is here since i promised it in my comment ...

**edit (2):**
i improve the first version of answer with solution introduced in the addendum. actually it differ from solution in addendum in the following:

- page size is not changed
- added caption and column head and toots for each page with this table
- font size is `\normalsize`

at testing of *mwe* with your document class, please remove `geometry` package  before test. it serve only for emulating (based on guessing) page layout as defined in your document class.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- your table is (again) very huge and without of some trick it can not be placed in text width without some tricks:

  - for table environment i select `ThreePartTable`
  - i used shortens with explanations at the bottom of table on each page using `TableNotes`
  - for marking of shortens i use `\tnote` from package `threeparttablex`
  - use of `sffamily` fonts (i concluded from option`Ariel` in loading `\documentclass`, that you use sans serif fonts)
- to obtain final form of table you need to compile document the least twice

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}      % i haven't "Thesis" style
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}% just for simulating page layout defined in your documentclass

% from your preamble i remove for your table all irrelevant packages
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, ltablex, makecell, threeparttablex}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % <----------------------

\usepackage[skip=1ex,labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \sffamily
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
     \item[a] Spectral resolution
    \item[b] MS: multi-spectral bands
    \item[c] Spatial resolution
    \item[d] Swath-width
    \item[e] Temporal resolution
    \item[f] Radiometric resolution
    \item[g] Mapping scale
    \item[h] Landsat-3 only\\[1ex]
%
\item[A]   A: scale 1:\num{2 500}
\item[B]   B: scale 1:\num{7 500}
\item[C]   C: scale 1:\num{10 000}
\item[D]   D: scale 1:\num{25 000}
\item[E]   E: scale 1:\num{40 000}
\item[F]   F: scale 1:\num{80 000}
\item[G]   G: scale 1:\num{100 000}
\item[H]   H: scale 1:\num{500 500}
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{       % <----------------------
    @{} *{6}{l} *{3}{c} l
    >{\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}R % <----------------------
    @{}}
    \caption{Characteristics of low and medium spatial resolution remote sensing systems and their applications}
    \label{T2.1}        \\
    \toprule
\thead[bl]{year}
    & \thead[bl]{Satellite}
        & \thead[bl]{Sensor}
            & \thead[bl]{SR\tnote{a} (nm)}
                & \thead[bl]{Bands\tnote{b}}
                    &  \thead[bl]{PS\tnote{c}\\ (m)}
                        &  \thead[bl]{C\tnote{d}\\ (km)}
                            &  \thead[bl]{RT\tnote{e}\\ (days)}
                                &  \thead[bl]{DR\tnote{f}\\ (bit)}
                                    & \thead[bl]{Scale\tnote{f}}
                                        & \thead[bl]{Applications} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption{Characteristics of low and medium spatial resolution remote sensing systems and their applications (cont.)}     \\
    \toprule
\\thead[bl]{year}
    & \thead[bl]{Satellite}
        & \thead[bl]{Sensor}
            & \thead[bl]{SR\tnote{a} (nm)}
                & \thead[bl]{Bands\tnote{b}}
                    &  \thead[bl]{PS\tnote{c}\\ (m)}
                        &  \thead[bl]{C\tnote{d}\\ (km)}
                            &  \thead[bl]{RT\tnote{e}\\ (days)}
                                &  \thead[bl]{DR\tnote{f}\\ (bit)}
                                    & \thead[bl]{Scale\tnote{f}}
                                        & \thead[bl]{Applications} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes\\
    \addlinespace
    \cmidrule{11-11}
    \multicolumn{11}{r}{\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
1972    &   \makecell[tl]{Landsat-1,\\ Landsat-2,\\ Landsat-3}
            &   MSS
                &   500 - 1100
                    &  \makecell[tl]{4 (MS)\\5\tnote{h}}
        &   80
            &   185
                &   18
                    &   6
                        &   A - G
        &   Land-use planning; vegetation inventories; crop growth and health assessments; discriminating different types and amounts of vegetation; and cartography \\
    \addlinespace
1984    &   Landsat-5
            &   TM
                &   \makecell[tl]{450 - 2,350\\ 10,400 - 12,350}
                    &   \makecell[tl]{6 (MS)\\ 1 (T)}
                        &   30
        &   185
            &   16
                &   8
                    &   G - H
        & Surface temperature; discriminating vegetation type; water penetration; plant and soil moisture measurements; and identification of hydrothermal alteration in certain rock types \\
    \addlinespace
1997    &   SeaStar
            &   SeaWiFS
                &   402 - 885
                    &   8 (MS)
        &   1,100
            &   2,800
                &   Daily
                    &   10
                        &   G - H
        &   The concentration of microscopic marine plants; phytoplankton based on the colour of the ocean         \\
    \addlinespace
1998    &   NOAA-15 & AVHRR/3
            &   580 - 12,500
                &   6 (MS)
                    &   1,090
        &   2,940
            &   Daily
                &   10
                    &   G - H
        &   Surface mapping (daytime); land–water boundaries; snow and ice detection; cloud mapping (daytime and night); sea surface temperature \\
    \addlinespace
1999    &   \makecell[tl]{Terra \&\\ Aqua}
            & MODIS & 620 - 14,3385
                &   \makecell[tl]{2 (MS)\\ 5 (MS)\\ 29 (MS \& T)}
                    &   \makecell[tl]{250\\ 500\\ 1000}
        &   2,330
            &   Daily
                &   12
                    &   G - H
        & Land, cloud, aerosols boundaries and properties; ocean colour, phytoplankton, biogeochemistry; atmospheric temperature; cirrus clouds and water vapour; ozone; surface and cloud temperature; cloud top altitude \\
    \addlinespace
1999    &   Terra
            &    MISR
                &   425 - 886
                    &   4 (MS)
        &   275
            &   360
                &   9
                    &   14
                        &   G - H
        &   Land use; ocean colour; air pollution; volcanic eruptions; desertification; deforestation; and soil erosion         \\
    \addlinespace
1999    &   Landsat7
            &   ETM+
                &   \makecell[tl]{450 - 2,350\\ 10,400 - 12,500\\ 500 - 900}
                    &   \makecell[tl]{6 (MS)\\ 1 (T)\\ 1 (PAN)}
        &   \makecell[tl]{30\\ 60\\ 15}
            &   185
                &   16
                    &   8
                        &   D - G
        &   Agriculture; forestry; land use; water resources and natural resource exploration; human population census and monitoring the growth of global urbanisation; deletion of coastal wetlands; and generating DEM \\
    \addlinespace
1999    &   Terra
            &   ASTER
                &   \makecell[tl]{520 - 860\\ 1,600 - 2,430\\ 8,125 - 11,650}
                    &   \makecell[tl]{3 (MS)\\ 6 (MS)\\ 5 (T)}
        &   \makecell[tl]{15\\ 30\\ 90}
            &   60
                &   16
                    &   \makecell[t]{8\\ 8\\ 12}
                        &   \makecell[tl]{A - E\\
                                          E - G\\
                                          G - H}
        &   Land surface climatology; vegetation and ecosystem dynamics; volcano monitoring; hydrology; geology and soils; land surface and land cover change \\
    \addlinespace
2002    &   SPOT5
            &   2 HRGs
                &   \makecell[tl]{500 - 890\\ 1,580 - 1,750\\ 480 - 710}
                    &   \makecell[tl]{3 (MS)\\ 1 (MS)\\ 1 (PAN)}
        &   \makecell[tl]{10\\ 20\\ 5}
            &   60
                &   26
                    &   8
                        &   \makecell[tl]{C - D\\
                                          C - D\\
                                          B - D}
        &   Urban and rural planning; land use and Infrastructure planning; telecommunications; oil and gas exploration and mining; environmental assessment, natural disaster management; marine studies; agriculture; and 3D terrain modelling \\
    \addlinespace
2013    &   Landsat8
            &   \makecell[tl]{OLI \&\\ TIRS}
                &   \makecell[tl]{435 - 1,551\\ 10,600 - 12,510\\ 503 - 676}
                    &   \makecell[tl]{8 (MS)\\ 2 (T)\\ 1 (PAN)}
        &   \makecell[tl]{30\\ 100\\ 15}
            &   185
                &   16
                    &   12
                        &   \makecell[tl]{F - G\\
                                          F - G\\
                                          A - E}
        &   Mineral exploration; vegetation analysis; large regional coverage; extensive archive for change detection; availability of imagery over cloud affected areas (detecting cirrus clouds); and coastal zone \\
    \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
   \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

**addendum (edited):**
another approach to solve your problems with fit huge table on one page is:

- remove definition for repeating caption and column heads and foots
- locally increase page size with `\changetext` on beginning and and of the `landscape` page with opposite parameters.
- reduce line spread in last column with `\linespread{0.84}\selectfont`
- reduce `\tabcolsep` size to `4pt`

(huh, don't like this ... myself would rather use the first solution)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}      % i haven't "Thesis" style
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, ltablex, makecell, threeparttablex}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % <----------------------

\usepackage[skip=1ex,labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\changetext{12em}{24em}{}{-2em}{}% <----------------------
%   meaning of parameters:
%   \changetext{add to text height}   (text width in landscape)
%              {add to text width}    (text heigth in landscape)
%              {add to right margin}  (bottom in landscape)
%              {add to left margin}   (top in landscape)
%              {add to column separation}
    \small
    \sffamily
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}    % <----------------------
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
     \item[a] Spectral resolution
    \item[b] MS: multi-spectral bands
    \item[c] Spatial resolution
    \item[d] Swath-width
    \item[e] Temporal resolution
    \item[f] Radiometric resolution
    \item[g] Mapping scale
    \item[h] Landsat-3 only\\[1ex]
%
    \item[A]   A: scale 1:\num{2 500}
    \item[B]   B: scale 1:\num{7 500}
    \item[C]   C: scale 1:\num{10 000}
    \item[D]   D: scale 1:\num{25 000}
    \item[E]   E: scale 1:\num{40 000}
    \item[F]   F: scale 1:\num{80 000}
    \item[G]   G: scale 1:\num{100 000}
    \item[H]   H: scale 1:\num{500 500}
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{       % <----------------------
    @{} *{6}{l} *{3}{c} l 
    >{\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}R % <----------------------
    @{}}
    \caption{Characteristics of low and medium spatial resolution remote sensing systems and their applications}
    \label{T2.1}        \\
    \toprule
\thead[bl]{year}
    & \thead[bl]{Satellite}
        & \thead[bl]{Sensor}
            & \thead[bl]{SR\tnote{a} (nm)}
                & \thead[bl]{Bands\tnote{b}}
                    &  \thead[bl]{PS\tnote{c}\\ (m)}
                        &  \thead[bl]{C\tnote{d}\\ (km)}
                            &  \thead[bl]{RT\tnote{e}\\ (days)}
                                &  \thead[bl]{DR\tnote{f}\\ (bit)}
                                    & \thead[bl]{Scale\tnote{f}}
                                        & \thead[bl]{Applications} \\
    \midrule
1972    &   \makecell[tl]{Landsat-1,\\ Landsat-2,\\ Landsat-3}
            &   MSS
                &   500 - 1100
                    &  \makecell[tl]{4 (MS)\\5\tnote{h}}
        &   80
            &   185
                &   18
                    &   6
                        &   A - G
        &   Land-use planning; vegetation inventories; crop growth and health assessments; discriminating different types and amounts of vegetation; and cartography \\
    \addlinespace
1984    &   Landsat-5
            &   TM
                &   \makecell[tl]{450 - 2,350\\ 10,400 - 12,350}
                    &   \makecell[tl]{6 (MS)\\ 1 (T)}
                        &   30
        &   185
            &   16
                &   8
                    &   G - H
        & Surface temperature; discriminating vegetation type; water penetration; plant and soil moisture measurements; and identification of hydrothermal alteration in certain rock types \\
    \addlinespace
1997    &   SeaStar
            &   SeaWiFS
                &   402 - 885
                    &   8 (MS)
        &   1,100
            &   2,800
                &   Daily
                    &   10
                        &   G - H
        &   The concentration of microscopic marine plants; phytoplankton based on the colour of the ocean         \\
    \addlinespace
1998    &   NOAA-15 & AVHRR/3
            &   580 - 12,500
                &   6 (MS)
                    &   1,090
        &   2,940
            &   Daily
                &   10
                    &   G - H
        &   Surface mapping (daytime); land–water boundaries; snow and ice detection; cloud mapping (daytime and night); sea surface temperature \\
    \addlinespace
1999    &   \makecell[tl]{Terra \&\\ Aqua}
            & MODIS & 620 - 14,3385
                &   \makecell[tl]{2 (MS)\\ 5 (MS)\\ 29 (MS \& T)}
                    &   \makecell[tl]{250\\ 500\\ 1000}
        &   2,330
            &   Daily
                &   12
                    &   G - H
        & Land, cloud, aerosols boundaries and properties; ocean colour, phytoplankton, biogeochemistry; atmospheric temperature; cirrus clouds and water vapour; ozone; surface and cloud temperature; cloud top altitude \\
    \addlinespace
1999    &   Terra
            &    MISR
                &   425 - 886
                    &   4 (MS)
        &   275
            &   360
                &   9
                    &   14
                        &   G - H
        &   Land use; ocean colour; air pollution; volcanic eruptions; desertification; deforestation; and soil erosion         \\
    \addlinespace
1999    &   Landsat7
            &   ETM+
                &   \makecell[tl]{450 - 2,350\\ 10,400 - 12,500\\ 500 - 900}
                    &   \makecell[tl]{6 (MS)\\ 1 (T)\\ 1 (PAN)}
        &   \makecell[tl]{30\\ 60\\ 15}
            &   185
                &   16
                    &   8
                        &   D - G
        &   Agriculture; forestry; land use; water resources and natural resource exploration; human population census and monitoring the growth of global urbanisation; deletion of coastal wetlands; and generating DEM \\
    \addlinespace
1999    &   Terra
            &   ASTER
                &   \makecell[tl]{520 - 860\\ 1,600 - 2,430\\ 8,125 - 11,650}
                    &   \makecell[tl]{3 (MS)\\ 6 (MS)\\ 5 (T)}
        &   \makecell[tl]{15\\ 30\\ 90}
            &   60
                &   16
                    &   \makecell[t]{8\\ 8\\ 12}
                        &   \makecell[tl]{A - E\\
                                          E - G\\
                                          G - H}
        &   Land surface climatology; vegetation and ecosystem dynamics; volcano monitoring; hydrology; geology and soils; land surface and land cover change \\
    \addlinespace
2002    &   SPOT5
            &   2 HRGs
                &   \makecell[tl]{500 - 890\\ 1,580 - 1,750\\ 480 - 710}
                    &   \makecell[tl]{3 (MS)\\ 1 (MS)\\ 1 (PAN)}
        &   \makecell[tl]{10\\ 20\\ 5}
            &   60
                &   26
                    &   8
                        &   \makecell[tl]{C - D\\
                                          C - D\\
                                          B - D}
        &   Urban and rural planning; land use and Infrastructure planning; telecommunications; oil and gas exploration and mining; environmental assessment, natural disaster management; marine studies; agriculture; and 3D terrain modelling \\
    \addlinespace
2013    &   Landsat8
            &   \makecell[tl]{OLI \&\\ TIRS}
                &   \makecell[tl]{435 - 1,551\\ 10,600 - 12,510\\ 503 - 676}
                    &   \makecell[tl]{8 (MS)\\ 2 (T)\\ 1 (PAN)}
        &   \makecell[tl]{30\\ 100\\ 15}
            &   185
                &   16
                    &   12
                        &   \makecell[tl]{F - G\\
                                          F - G\\
                                          A - E}
        &   Mineral exploration; vegetation analysis; large regional coverage; extensive archive for change detection; availability of imagery over cloud affected areas (detecting cirrus clouds); and coastal zone \\
    \bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
        \end{tabularx}            % <----------------------
\end{ThreePartTable}
\changetext{-12em}{-24em}{}{2em}{}% <----------------------
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Iris, as i promise ...my answer is above.

Comment: @Zargo, thank you very much for your help. You are amazing. The table is now more elegant and well-organised. Please, I managed to put this table in one landscape page frame (as shown in the pic) but the text is very small, and the table is not in the centre of the page (as stated in the comment of the post). Some friends suggested me "Try putting the units in columns 3,5, etc. In the next row. You will have more space to experiment with", but I do not know how I can do it. Any suggestions or help, please. Making this table on one page would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Iris, i not recommend to squeeze table on one page. the fonts will become to small. however if you persist to do this, then see addendum to my answer :-(.

Comment: @Zargo, this is so awesome, and you are awesome too :) But I have a problem with using "\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}" and "\newgeometry{hmargin={20mm,5mm},
             vmargin=20mm}". I cannot use them with the document style. I do not know why. It gives me errors. Is it possible not use them and get the same result? Sorry for any inconvenience but your addendum is really great. Highly appreciate it.

Comment: @iris, don't overdo it with praises ... i was afraid, that this would not work with your `\documentclass`. apparently it doesn't support `geometry` package or even clash with it. where i can download it? btw, i not recommend to push table on one page. try omit all `geometry` stuff and then stick with table on two pages. i will improve the first answer asap.

Comment: @Iris, i edited my answer again. now the `\newgeometry` is removed and hopefully this corrected solution will work with your `\documentclass`

Comment: @Zarko-Thank you for your help and your time. I always run the script individually and then cut the part with its packages and run them with the whole doc. When I run the code as you stated the new version of it here, I've got this error "Undefined control sequence. \end{tabularx}" .

Comment: @Zarko-Please, I could not run the last version of the table (without geometry package). There are some errors there, such as "Undefined control sequence. \endlastfoot" and "Misplaced alignment tab character &. 1972 &" and "Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph"..Please, I need to your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ups, accidentally i remove package `siunitx` from preamble. now i add it and now all works as expected ;-)

Comment: "@Zarko-Thank you very much. I managed to run the script individually but when I took only the table part, it gave me this error "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \end{tabularx}".  Sorry for any inconvenience, but please how can I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started please have a look to the following MWE. I reduced the preamble to be minimalized for the given problem, changed the class (where does your used class come from), but left your codes `\hbox{\strut` in the code (resulting that text is overlapping columns; please change that for your needs ...).

The MWE

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage[skip=1ex,labelfont=bf,font=small]{caption}

%\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{%
    %\small                              % for better fit text into cells
    %\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth} % that caption width is equal table width
    %\setlist[itemize]{  nosep,          % <-- new list setup
        %leftmargin = *,
        %before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
        %after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    %}
%}% end of AtBeginEnvironment

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape} %\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  {\small %
  \begin{longtable}{| p{1cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{1cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{3cm} |}
    \caption{Characteristics of low and medium spatial resolution remote sensing systems and their applications}
  \label{T2.1}
\endfirsthead
\hline
\textbf{Launch year} & \textbf{Satellite} & \textbf{Sensor} & \textbf{Spectral range\textsuperscript{a} (nm)} & \textbf{Bands\textsuperscript{b}} & \textbf{Pixel size\textsuperscript{c} (m)} & \textbf{Coverage\textsuperscript{d} (km)} & \textbf{Revisit time\textsuperscript{e} (days)} & \textbf{Dynamic range\textsuperscript{f} (bit)} & \textbf{Mapping scale} & \textbf{Applications} \\ 
\hline
1972  & Landsat-1, 2, 3  & MSS  & 500 - 1100 &  \vtop{\hbox{\strut 4 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 5 (Landsat-3 only)}} & 80 & 185 & 18 & 6 & 1:2500 - 1:100,000 & Land-use planning; vegetation inventories; crop growth and health assessments; discriminating different types and amounts of vegetation; and cartography \\ \hline
            1984 & Landsat-5 & TM & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 450 - 2,350}\hbox{\strut 10,400 - 12,350}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 6 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 1(T)}} & 30 & 185 & 16 & 8 & 1:2500 - 1:100,000 & Surface temperature; discriminating vegetation type; water penetration; plant and soil moisture measurements; and identification of hydrothermal alteration in certain rock types \\ \hline
            1997 & SeaStar & SeaWiFS & 402 - 885 & 8 (MS) & 1,100 & 2,800 & Daily & 10 & 1:100,000 - 1:500,000 & The concentration of microscopic marine plants; phytoplankton based on the colour of the ocean \\ \hline
            1998 & NOAA-15 & AVHRR/3 & 580 - 12,500 & 6 (MS) & 1,090 & 2,940 & Daily & 10 & 1:100,000 - 1:500,000 & Surface mapping (daytime); land–water boundaries; snow and ice detection; cloud mapping (daytime and night); sea surface temperature \\ \hline
            1999 & Terra \& Aqua & MODIS & 620 - 14,3385 & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 2 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 5 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 29 (MS \&T)}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 250}\hbox{\strut 500}\hbox{\strut 1000}} & 2,330 & Daily & 12 & 1:100,000 - 1:500,000 & Land, cloud, aerosols boundaries and properties; ocean colour, phytoplankton, biogeochemistry; atmospheric temperature; cirrus clouds and water vapour; ozone; surface and cloud temperature; cloud top altitude \\ \hline
            1999 & Terra & MISR & 425 - 886 & 4 (MS) & 275 & 360 & 9 & 14 & 1:100,000 - 1:500,000 & Land use; ocean colour; air pollution; volcanic eruptions; desertification; deforestation; and soil erosion \\ \hline
            1999 & Landsat7 & ETM+ & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 450 - 2,350}\hbox{\strut 10,400 - 12,500}\hbox{\strut 500 - 900}}  & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 6 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 1 (T)}\hbox{\strut 1 (PAN)}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 30}\hbox{\strut 60}\hbox{\strut 15}} & 185 & 16 & 8 & 1:2,500 - 1:100,000 & LAgriculture; forestry; land use; water resources and natural resource exploration; human population census and monitoring the growth of global urbanisation; deletion of coastal wetlands; and generating DEM \\ \hline
            1999 & Terra & ASTER & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 520 - 860}\hbox{\strut 1,600 - 2,430}\hbox{\strut 8,125 - 11,650}}  & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 3 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 6 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 5 (T)}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 15}\hbox{\strut 30}\hbox{\strut 90}} & 60 & 16 & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 8}\hbox{\strut 8}\hbox{\strut 12}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 1:2,500 - 1:40,000}\hbox{\strut 1:40,000 - 1:100,000}\hbox{\strut 1:100,000 - 1:500,000}} & Land surface climatology; vegetation and ecosystem dynamics; volcano monitoring; hydrology; geology and soils; land surface and land cover change \\ \hline
            2002 & SPOT5 & 2 HRGs & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 500 - 890}\hbox{\strut 1,580 - 1,750}\hbox{\strut 480 - 710}}  & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 3 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 1 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 1 (PAN)}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 10}\hbox{\strut 20}\hbox{\strut 5}} & 60 & 26 & 8 & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 1:10,000 - 1:25,000}\hbox{\strut 1:10,000 - 1:25,000}\hbox{\strut 1:7,500 - 1:25,000}} & Urban and rural planning; land use and Infrastructure planning; telecommunications; oil and gas exploration and mining; environmental assessment, natural disaster management; marine studies; agriculture; and 3D terrain modelling \\ \hline
            2013 & Landsat8 & OLI \& TIRS & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 435 - 1,551}\hbox{\strut 10,600 - 12,510}\hbox{\strut 503 - 676}}  & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 8 (MS)}\hbox{\strut 2 (T)}\hbox{\strut 1 (PAN)}} & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 30}\hbox{\strut 100}\hbox{\strut 15}} & 185 & 16 & 12 & \vtop{\hbox{\strut 1:80,000 - 1:100,000}\hbox{\strut 1:80,000 - 1:100,000}\hbox{\strut 1:2,500 - 1:40,000}} & Mineral exploration; vegetation analysis; large regional coverage; extensive archive for change detection; availability of imagery over cloud affected areas (detecting cirrus clouds); and coastal zone \\  \hline

            \multicolumn{11}{|l|}{\textsuperscript{a}Spectral resolution, \textsuperscript{b}MS multi-spectral bands, \textsuperscript{c}Spatial resolution, \textsuperscript{d}Swath-width, \textsuperscript{e}Temporal resolution, \textsuperscript{f}Radiometric resolution} \\

            \hline
        \end{longtable}
          }
    \end{landscape} %\end{table}
\end{document}  % The End
```

gives the result:

[image: resulting first page of table]