# Table caption alignment in threeparttablex-longtable combination

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, geometry, threeparttablex

I am new to StackExchange, so any suggestions to improve my question framing are welcome.

I have some trouble getting the caption of my table aligned. Since I need a landscape, multipage table, I am using threeparttablex combined with longtable. I figured out that commenting out the margin adjustments in line 10 in the MWE below fixes my problem, but I do like to keep my margins that way in the rest of my document.

Note: The captions of the other 'regular' threeparttables (no x, no longtable) in my document are fine. Also, I tried \centering at multiple locations in this table, which didn't help.

My question is: how to align the table caption with this table, while also keeping my margins at 2.6cm? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[margin=2.6cm]{geometry} %commenting this out fixes the caption alignment

%adjust table caption setup
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=spaced, skip=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
        \small
        \item \textit{Note.} Table notes
    \end{TableNotes}

    \begin{longtable}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}

        \caption{My caption}\\ 

        \toprule
        Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textit{My caption (continued)}}\\ %cheating a little bit here
        \toprule
        Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header \\
        \midrule    
        \endhead

        \midrule
        \multicolumn{7}{r}{{\textit{Continued on next page}}} \\
        \midrule
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule

        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot

        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    \end{longtable}

\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table caption not aligned with table]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Zarko, but I need the `singlelinecheck=false` because my table caption should be on the top left (and not in the middle).

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Inquisitive Lurker, I hadn't thought of manually adjusting the caption yet and it does the job, thanks! Of course it's not super elegant and I am still wondering why this is happening, but for now it helps me continue :)

Comment: @Zarko no problem!

Comment: @Elisabeth I turned my comment into an answer, since I'd made a small mistake - you'll need to adjust the margins separately for each table, because they depend on table width.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker yes, I figured that out too :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: It should be noted that longtable also implements most of the features of threeparttable, so you really don't need both, or at least don't nest them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better, automatic solution for this, but as a quick fix, you can adjust the caption's margins manually:

`\captionsetup{margin=1.4cm}`

You could set that at the start of the document, but since your tables probably all have different widths, you'll likely have to adjust this separately for each of them: Place the above line at the beginning of each table, like this:

```
%[...]
\begin{longtable}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}

        \captionsetup{margin=1.4cm} % <---  adjust as needed
        \caption{My caption}\\ 
%[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to define width of caption:

```
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\dimexpr17cm+14\tabcolsep}
```

where `17cm` is sum of columns widths and `14\tabcolsep` sum of `tabcolsep` lengths around them. complete code is:

```
%%%% 3parttablex                                            %%%%%
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
%   my answer ...                                   2017-10-14  %
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395852/             %
%       a-long-table-in-the-landscape-page/396077#396077        &
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
%   special:    table notes are inserted in                     %
%               \endfoot and \endlastfoot                       %
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array,
            booktabs,
            longtable,
            makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[1ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,
                     justification=raggedright,
                     singlelinecheck=false,
                     labelsep=spaced,
                     skip=1ex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text in captions
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \sffamily
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \centering
\begin{ThreePartTable}[
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\dimexpr17cm+14\tabcolsep}
%
\begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
\note{General table notes}

\item[*] first note
\item[**] second note
\end{TableNotes}
%
    \begin{longtable}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}
\caption{My caption. \lipsum[66]}\\
     \toprule
Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption*{My caption. \lipsum[66]}\\
    \toprule
Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header & Header \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{7}{r}{{\textit{Continued on next page}}} \\
\endfoot
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{longtable}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

[image]

note: i slightly change design of your table (distances in caption, rules in table)